# strcpy() causes invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, destructor, strcpy

I'm trying to have an object named `PReader` (with a function named `Execute()`, taking no arguments) have a filename passed in through the constructor so `Execute()` can access it. The way I'm trying to set it up involves having the constructor allocate the memory for a string, then copy it over, and setting up a destructor for it. I know it's awkward, but I know this setup will make future additions to my project easier.

Here's how my object is currently set up:

```
#include <PReader.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

PReader::PReader(const char *f)
{
    filename = new char[strlen(f)+1];
    strcpy(filename, f);
}

PReader::~PReader()
{
    delete [] filename;
}

void PReader::Execute(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(this->filename, "rb");
    ...
}
```

This is giving me the error:

```
PReader.C: In constructor ‘PReader::PReader(char*)’:
PReader.C:10:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
  strcpy(filename, f);
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:11:0,
                 from PReader.C:2:
/usr/include/string.h:30:8: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strcpy(char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 char  *_EXFUN(strcpy,(char *__restrict, const char *__restrict));
```

For so few lines of code, I'm kind of surprised I'm missing something here. What can I do to ensure that conversion succeeds how I want it?

EDIT: PReader.h:

```
#include "source.h"

#ifndef PREADER_H
#define PREADER_H

class PReader : public Source
{
    public:
        const char* filename;
        PReader(const char *filename);
        virtual ~PReader();
        virtual void Execute();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please include in your question the class definition of `PReader` from `PReader.h`.

Comment: And also what is `filename`.

Comment: Added `PReader.h`. `filename` is a `const char*`.

Comment: Do the universe (and you) a favor and use std::string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you defined `filename` to be a `const char*`. Make it a `char*` instead, so you can actually modify it (using `strcpy`) :

```
char* filename;
```

Or better yet, since this is C++, why not make use of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) ?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Just been using char arrays out of old (bad) C habits, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between these two declarations

```
const char * filename;
```

and

```
char * const  filename;
```

The first one declares a pointer to a constant object  of type `const char`. The pointer itself can be changed for example as `++filename` but the object that pointed by the pointer may not be changed as for example `++*filename`. So you may not use such a pointer in function `std::strcpy` as the first argument.

The second one declares a constant pointer to a non-constant object. So the pointer itself may not be changed. For example the compiler will issue an error for expression `++filename`. But you may change the object pointed to by the pointer. For example `++*filename;` Such a pointer you may use as the first argument in function `std::strcpy`.

And at last you can define non-constant pointer that points to a non-constant object

```
char * filename;
```

In this case you can change the pointer itself and change the object pointed by the pointer.

So in your class ypu should define filename either as

```
char * const  filename;
```

or as

```
char * filename;
```

Take into account that pointers can be defined as

```
const char * const  filename = "String Literal";
```

that is this statement defines a constant pointer to a constant object. You may change neither the pointer itself nor the object pointed by the pointer.

The equivalent declaration is

```
const char * constexpr  filename = "String Literal";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your header, you have

```
const char* filename;
```

and you are trying to `strcpy` into it. This is not allowed. Change that to

```
char* filename;
```